# Python requests encoding issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

I use python requests to make get request to this [url](http://213.139.159.46/prj-wwvauskunft/projects/gus/daten/index.jsp?). Here is the code snippet.

```
url = 'http://213.139.159.46/prj-wwvauskunft/projects/gus/daten/index.jsp?'
params = {'id': 2619521210}

response = requests.get(
    url,
    params=params
)

print(response.status_code)

text = response.text
content = response.content
```

I run the same code in Python2.7 and Python3.6

When I compare text variable between the two versions, they are different. But content between the two versions are the same. I am confused as to why content is the same but text are different. Shouldn't the text be the same as well if they are using the same encoding to encode text to content?

I used **chardet** to detect the encoding of content, both versions ended with **ISO-8859-1**. What's could be the possible reason for them not to use **utf-8**. Is it just a preference?

Also, when I do:

```
content.replace('span', '')
```

In Python2, it works. In Python3, it would throw the this error.
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`(Using **b'span'** and **b''** would solve the probelm)

But when I do:

```
text.replace('span', '')
```

Both version works. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guaranty for `Python 2` and `Python 3` compatibility (neither backward nor forward). Read e.g. [Python 2 vs Python 3: Key Differences](https://www.guru99.com/python-2-vs-python-3.html). For instance, if your script was modified (add following code snippet to the end):

```
print('type(text)   ', type(text))
print('type(content)', type(content))
```

**Output**:

```
py -2 D:\Python\SO3\61954902.py
```

> ```
> 200
> ('type(text)   ', <type 'unicode'>)
> ('type(content)', <type 'str'>)
> ```

```
py -3 D:\Python\SO3\61954902.py
```

> ```
> 200
> type(text)    <class 'str'>
> type(content) <class 'bytes'>
> ```

---

For the sake of completeness, the script is as follows:

```
type D:\Python\SO3\61954902.py
```

> ```
> import requests
> url = 'http://213.139.159.46/prj-wwvauskunft/projects/gus/daten/index.jsp?'
> params = {'id': 2619521210}
>
> response = requests.get(
>     url,
>     params=params
> )
>
> print(response.status_code)
>
> text = response.text
> content = response.content
> print('type(text)   ', type(text))
> print('type(content)', type(content))
> ```

Comment: Thx. Yeah, it makes sense. The problem I have is I have lots of similar scrapes and need to migrate them from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6. Had a lots of ```if six.PY2``` in the code which is messy. Trying to find a simpler way to make it both versions compatible.